# How can I print the values from a list of JSON objects to a div after being returned via Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can successfully return the the list of objects via an Ajax call, and I can see them in my console:

[image]

How can I iterate over each object (in the above example there are 1) and then print one of the values, i.e. notificationText below, to a series of divs?

**JQuery/Ajax:**

```
<script>
    function LoadReplies(convoMessageId) {
        $('#test123').html('<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>');
        console.log("Message ID: " + convoMessageId);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index?handler=Replies",
            headers: {
                "XSRF-TOKEN": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: convoMessageId,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                $('#convo' + convoMessageId).modal('show');
                $.each(response, function (idx, obj) {
                    console.log(obj[0].value);
                    $("#test123").html(obj[0].value);
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**JSON List:**

[image]

I can retrieve the value I want now but it doesn't render to the div:

```
$("#test123").html(obj[0].value);
```

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` and add that to the question instead of the image. When you see that output, you might be able to solve your problem :)

Comment: @Shyju I made some progress but it doesn't seem to render to the div?

Comment: @Shyju Oh nevermind. That's an html issue. There were more than one div with id test123 (did not realize it was within a template loop). All works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the Div will show the HTML only, you have to generate the HTML string out of the JSON or the data. For example in your success callback function, I would do the simplest as below:

```
var generatedHtml = ['<dl>'];
$.each(response, function (idx, obj) {
    generatedHtml.push(`<dt>label1:</dt> <dd>${obj[idx].prop1}</dd> <dt>label2:</dt>${obj[idx].prop2}</dd>`);
});
generatedHtml.push('</dl>');
$("#test123").html(generatedHtml.join(''));
```

I didn't test it myself, but it should work...

Comment: Thanks! That's very efficient.

Comment: Btw, how do you access the nested objects? For example, ``${obj[1]["username"].value}``?

Comment: If you need just a few properties of the nested objects, then you access them directly as you mentioned. Otherwise, you can iterate over the keys of the nested object, and get their values in the iteration. For example: `$.each(Object.keys(obj[idx]), function(keyIndex, key){ console.log(obj[idx][key]);})`

Comment: If you need just a few properties of the nested objects, then you access them directly as you mentioned. Otherwise, you can iterate over the keys of the nested object, and get their values in the iteration. For example: `$.each(Object.keys(obj[idx]), function(keyIndex, key){ console.log(obj[idx][key]);})`

Comment: @Naddem Jamali I keep getting ``ReferenceError: username is not defined[Learn More]`` when I do something like ``obj[1][username].value`` or `obj[1]["username"].value``. It doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @MartinErlic your sample data shows that the object doesn't contain 'username' property, hence it is not being returned!

Comment: That key is within the author object, as per the highlighted image in my question. I managed to figure it out this out. Thanks!